# Breaking the tie by removing the last element from the list in python

Tags: python

I am trying to return the majority, or break a tie by keep removing the last element from the list. This is what I have been trying to do but does not seem to work

Given an input of a list label = [4,4,4,3,3,3,5,5,5,6,6,6] I am trying to get an output of [4,4,4,3,3] where 4 is the majority here after removing keep removing the last element from the list.

```
label = [4,4,4,3,3,3,5,5,5,6,6,6]
test_dict = Counter(label)

x = list(test_dict.values())

for i in label:
    if(x.count(x[0]) == len(x)):
        label = label[:-1]
        x = list(Counter(label).values())
        
print(label)
print(x)
```

This loop only go once, how would I fix this?

Comment: Is "Counter" a function you have created? Can you share its code here to make this more reproducible?

Answer (score 0):

This will iterate over `label` and `pop` the last value, until there is only one "max" value inside of `label`:

```
def tie_breaker(x):
    x_set = set(x)
    x_count = [x.count(i) for i in x_set]
    return x_count.count(max(x_count)) > 1

label = [4,4,4,3,3,3,5,5,5,6,6,6] 
while tie_breaker(label):
    label.pop()
print(label)
```

The reason *your* code "only loops once" (it actually iterates over each value of `label`) is because of the if-statement `if(x.count(x[0]) == len(x)):`, which is only `True` the first time around.